# Pentaho PDI very slow when i access pentaho server

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I have jobs and transformations in a pentaho server but when try to open, edit, save and close them i have to wait a long time...when I try to move a step it's like my screen is at 10fps.

How can i improve the spoon's performance, somebody helps me.

the pentaho server is in a cetos machine with 16G ram

I modified the spoon.sh to Xms5G and Xmx10G

There is other parameter Xx maspermsize that is 256 mb (i dont know whate means this parameter)

Answer (score 0):

One thing we found was under "Administration" in the Pentaho Users Console" Click on Settings.  There is options for "Deleting Generated Files Now".   Each time Pentaho Server runs a job it creates files.   Over time these build up.   You can also set a schedule on the same page to remove these files on a scheduled basis.   Our time to browse Job/Transformations went from almost 2 minutes to 5-10 seconds.